# How can I draw only 8 character per line in a CTFrameRef?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drawing, core-graphics, core-text

I'm trying to draw in a *CTFrameRef* only **8 character per line** but I don't know how to do this with *CTFrameRef*.

I've read "[Manual Line Breaking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW16)", but they use CTLine and I think use CTFrameRef it's simpler.

Maybe with some kind of frame setter or changing CGPath this could be possible.

This is my code right now (I've deleted comment lines with my testing code about the problem):

```cpp
// Prepare font
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("LucidaSansUnicode"), 16, NULL);

// Create path        
    CGMutablePathRef gpath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(gpath, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200));

// Create an attributed string
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (newcontext, kCGTextFillStroke); 
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(newcontext, 0.0, 1.0);

CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName };
CFTypeRef values[] = { font };
CFDictionaryRef attr = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys,
    (const void **)&values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]),
    &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, 
    CFSTR("Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur."), attr);

CTFramesetterRef framesetter = 
    CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attrString);

CTFrameRef theFrame = 
    CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,
    CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrString)), gpath, NULL);

CTFrameDraw(theFrame, newcontext);

// Clean up... CFRelease...

// Getting TIFF image
```

I get the following picture:

[image: Wrong Image]

But I want something like this (there are differences because this image has been made with photoshop):

[image: Wanted Image]

Thanks and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that `CTFrame` is simpler for this kind of problem than `CTLine`? You want an unusual line breaking algorithm. `CTFrame` uses the default line-break algorithm.

Break your input into 8-character `NSAttributedString` runs and create `CTLineRef` objects with them, then draw them. This should be extremely straight-forward. What is causing the confusion?